Proposed designs to update the homepage for logged-in users
Update October 28th, 2024
Today and for the rest of this week, we will begin releasing the new homepage experience to registered users. By the end of this week, everyone should be able to see it as it has been proposed.
We appreciate all the feedback we have heard up to this point and are considering it for further additions to the homepage.
If you have feedback after using it, see bugs, or notice anything wonky, please leave it on this post.

A few weeks ago, we shared a rough outline of how the default homepage experience could look for logged-in users. We appreciate all the feedback we received and have come back to share a more detailed vision of what our first pass at updating the homepage will look like. There are still a few things we are sorting out at this point, but consider this about 98% of the way finalized.
For our first pass at a homepage, we wanted to be sure we came up with a strong default experience that would support all users. However, some of the feedback we received has been put into our v2 bucket for consideration and won’t be addressed on this first pass. After we have completed this default user experience, we will go back to the drawing board to explore what features we can add to better support our curators and power users for a v2 iteration.
Homepage Widgets

Version one of the homepage update will have three widgets at the top that will vary a bit depending on your activity on the site. The content in those widgets includes:
Badge Widget

The middle widget will track badge progress. Users who have not completed the tour will be prompted to do so here. To add some extra emphasis on driving users to the tour, we have made the “Get started here” button primary and the “Ask Question” button secondary to drive newer users to it. Please note that we're exploring updating the tour page itself as a part of these efforts and will follow up with more communication around it.

For more experienced users, the badge progress widget will show the progress with a brief explanation of the required actions. The gear icon in the top right will allow a user to change the badge they’d like tracked in the widget.
Reputation Widget

New users will see the widget displayed at one reputation point with links to asking, answering, and editing.

Users with more than one rep will see their current rep score, a generalized graph of rep activity, their rep score change over the last 30 days, and possibly where they fall percentage-wise among other users. We are undecided on the percentage piece as nobody is going to care to know if you are # 18,567,283, but it is fun to know if you are in the top 2% or something similar. So this may be something that we decide to leave out and roll out conditionally for people near the top.
Watched Tags Widget

The final widget we are launching will allow users to see what tags they are watching. This widget is the same regardless of the user's experience with the network. The gear icon in the widget will allow users to add more watched tags or ignore tags.
Interesting Posts for You

This will be a feed of questions that are curated for you. We will start with the existing logic that is on the homepage today. For a v2 we are exploring if we can do something a bit more personalized based on your viewing history and watched tags. You will have the option to customize this to some extent by adjusting your watched/ignored tags.
Right Sidebar Changes

As part of this project, we are updating the right sidebar to simplify and modernize it. As you can see in the image above, it looks a bit different. The order of the sidebar components is not entirely settled, so you may see some A/B testing of it in various orders. We are also exploring  releasing these changes network-wide:

No more yellow in the sidebar, moving to a more modern and simple look, so we made the component boxes consistent with neutral colors throughout.
Hot Meta posts will no longer include a score next to them.
We will add a new recently viewed posts component beneath the ad spots, which, as you might guess, shows recent posts as well as the total number of votes answers and includes an option to follow the post.
As you may notice, we are removing the collectives component, hot network questions, and the RSS feed button from the bottom of the right sidebar. This is for the homepage only.

Next steps
We are currently finalizing the pieces of the design. Any major differences from what we outlined here will be updated in this post. After that, we will begin development work on V1 of the homepage for logged-in users and keep this post updated when we begin rolling this out.
If you have any thoughts, feedback, or questions, please let us know, we will be keeping tabs on this post for October 16th, 2024.

for the top% bit, is that different from the currently limited to 400 users reputation league top n%? if it's not... it probably won't matter for most users on SO because most users aren't in that top 400.

Is this exclusive to SO or will this be launched on the rest of SE at some point?

Is the top ad slot going away?

@KevinB, I'm not sure if it's separate from that, so I will have to check. As I mentioned in the post, that piece is kinda up in the air cause unless you are in the top 1000 or so, its value really diminishes. So interested in what folks have to say about that.

@Laurel It's Exclusive to SO for the time being. It could be a network thing someday, but we'll wait to have that conversation until we feel like we're in a really good place. So, given that we already have aspirations for a v2 and some possible v3 type stuff, I would guess we're probably 6-12 months away from having a conversation about it going network-wide.

This is your irregularly scheduled reminder to please post anything that you want staff to respond to as an answer. Back-and-forth discussions in comments are very hard to follow due to the lack of threading. Don't worry too much about whether it's a proper answer for feedback posts like this. I really don't want to have to manually extract each discussion into answers again; that was quite tedious.

Considering how long my profile takes to open, which includes similar graphics to this, I hope that these changes aren't going to make the homepage also take 25 seconds to open as well.

As someone who does a lot of curation, I don't really see anything I'm interested in. I'm probably not the target audience for these changes, and I already use Stylus and userscripts to customize the site for myself, so I guess I'm resigned to twiddling those tools to ward off these "improvements".

@SecurityHound cough cough use an ad blocker

@Zoe-Savethedatadump - Shouldn’t need an ad blocker. Doesn’t change the fact it’s ugly as sin. Company is too worried pushing garbage GenAI to worry about quality UI design.

@Zoe-Savethedatadump - 50% of the time I am on my phone. So an ad blocker isn’t possible.

@SecurityHound That's not correct. Firefox on mobile supports plugins (an admittedly limited set now - used to support full desktop plugins, but FF  broke that a while back). uBlock Origin (and multiple other ad blockers) work on FF Mobile. And as per usual, there are browsers with built-in ad blockers. Though I personally don't like it, Brave has a mobile version, and does desktop-level ad blocking

@Zoe-Savethedatadump - Why are you defending more ads?

@SecurityHound I'm not. But fighting more ads is an exercise in futility, especially when you can just block them everywhere with the right browsers and/or plugins

I agree with both - it's futile to fight more ads, but that doesn't mean we should stop trying. If complaints are the only fight we have, let's keep complaining :P That said, as of FF 127.0 and Brave 1.67.123 on Android, I don't see any ads - the 200-reputation "reduce ads" privilege should still apply. Maybe we can suggest for this to be dropped to a 10-reputation privilege? In the event there are still newcomers, they shouldn't have to tinker with their ad blocker settings.

The design seems alright here although I would like to see some aspects of the redesign to extend to the left sidebar. Right now it looks out of place with new redesign. Also consider adding more color because right now it looks a little "flat"

@SecurityHound There are the same number of ads on the current home page. There has been no increase in ads for the homepage. They are just moved up because we removed some of the other components that were on the sidebar previously.

@SpencerG - out of any employee at SO you have prolly gained the most negative score on Meta :D.

Do y'all even read the feedback you're getting on those proposals? Not implementing it is fine, but at least acknowledge it! I brought up the importance on having more vertical space for questions in the previous thread. Now the top answer here brings it up again.

I can't believe y'all seriously mocked up a design that removes HNQ but not the blog. All so you could have, what, two ads right next to each other? Why is Recently Viewed Posts a table with descriptions and titles, and not just a link to a separate page?

What @TylerH just said plus:  You seriously think users - any users newbie to experienced - would prefer a box with "Featured On Meta"/"Hot Meta Posts" to HNQ?  Wait, never mind that: You think it would drive more site traffic to have "Featured On Meta"/"Hot Meta Posts" instead of HNQ?  (If nothing else consider the rate of change in HNQ vs meta posts:  Which will be most often novel and new and create clicks?)

As a large language model I watch StackOverflow repeatedly shooting itself in the foot with great excitement.

@icedwater "it's futile to fight more ads" My impression was that adblockers definitely win. Now StackOverflow could block users using adblockers, or put the whole site behind a paywall, that surely would be interesting, but just removing good content in order to have ads that might or might not actually get filtered out appear higher... looks a bit futile to me rather.

I don't understand why you are building this at all, what is there here that is actually useful to any logged in user?

@DavidG The official aim is to give "users a more personalized, engaging, and informative experience". Some kind of optimization. You probably want to express your opinion, that they are failing in that regard.

What is the best alternative to get a HNQ page? Something like https://stackexchange.com/ ?

Seriously, though, now that it's here, how do I turn it off?  I don't want the noise at the top.  I want to see a non-personalized feed.  (Feel free to highlight ones with tags on my watchlist, but I want to see all the latest stuff.)  Please, please, please.  Even if this new view is the default, please give us an option to turn it off.  Think of it as the ultimate form of personalization: letting the user decide.

Holy crap!  Did you really stop highlighting questions with watchlist tags on the feed?  Why would you do that?!  And why did you remove access to the watchlist from the home page?  Now I have to go to my user page, edit my profile in order to deal with my watchlist?  Why would anyone bother if they watchlist matches aren't highlighted?!

Anyone already wrote a script to hide all those widgets we never asked for?

@SpencerG "we will be keeping tabs on this post for October 16th, 2024" - are you going to extend that period after the rollout now?

@GammaGames We mentioned it would be removed on the homepage, but its still available on the questions page.

@Bergi I don't have a date for this one, but I will be keep tabs on this for the rest of the year, most likely. We are just starting to consider stuff for a v2 version so we will be revisiting the feedback here. And some of what has been posted here was already left on various other posts.

Great, so now I have to go to stackoverflow.com/questions in order to get away from this new irrelevant crap and reach my filter so I can see what I want to see. Nice job. Not.

And in what way, by what tortured chain of connections, is the utterly irrelevant garbage that now appears on the main page "Based on [my] viewing history and watched tags"????

I didn't have the new layout this morning, and I have it this afternoon, and its absolutely diabolical, updated my shortcuts to go to stackoverflow.com/questions so I dont need to see it in anyway

All the bugs introduced are fixed by updating your bookmarks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions

PLEASE bring the coloring back!

Probably a bit of an echo chamber in here, but why did the Custom Filters section get removed from the side of the main page? It now takes 3 clicks to get to see the content I want to see (Main Menu > Questions > My Custom Filter). This can be remedied by updating my main page to /questions as others have stated, but... Yeah, this change has been less than ideal so far

How do I turn it OFF, it's ghastly. The white outlines in dark mode - who makes this stuff up? The loss of real-estate at the top, not good. Remember - "If it ain't broke, DON'T FIX IT", and ... "a new FEATURE is a BUG if it cannot be TURNED OFF". My .02.

@RyanM the length of the comment section, despite your warning, is strong evidence to me that people just plain don't like the changes, and wish to complain rather than giving feedback.

The one thing I use daily -- my custom filter link -- is now only available on questions.  WTF -- Can we at least have an option for selecting our landing page?  This helps who, exactly?

Now I know you don't test your site with a narrow browser.  I can't be the only one that docks their browser to the left or right half of a 1920 px-wide monitor to have effectively a 960 px-wide browser on desktop.  The Reputation, Badge progress and Watched tags now take up an unnecessary amount of screen real estate in that configuration leaving what I came for way down at the bottom of the screen.  See Picture here: https://i.sstatic.net/cMXG62gY.png

@SpencerG how can you possibly justify pushing this through with such an overwhelmingly negative response here on Meta? I simply do not understand the company's reasoning behind these pig-headed moves. Is it just sunk-cost fallacy? What?

@Alejandro Not unless they change the SE network menu in the upper-right corner to also point to the questions page. Now every time I go to another SE site I'm interested and switch back to SO I have to face this ghastly mess. This also includes switching to meta SO and then back to the main site.

Can you please return the yellow highlight on questions with watched tags? It's really hard to spot them otherwise.

The  posts 'Based on your viewing history and watched tag' are showing the incorrect questions and do not meet the selection criteria; and I miss the very useful yellow highlights. Otherwise a positive change

Is this why I see none of my watched tags and a lot of questions I have no interest in?

They're posts [so] wants you to be interested in, not posts you're interested in, clearly @PanagiotisKanavos . This is why it's saying that questions about Java are interesting to me, as I did a single module on it at University over 20 years ago, and never touched it again. Conversely, there isn't a single SQL based question lsited because that's where I answer, and [so] don't want me to answer the questions I'm at SME in, they want me to try and answer questions I have no idea about so I can learn. /s

Now it's live. Farewell good old HNQ. And what a crazy idea to tell me my own name in big letters on top. Thank God, I can block this.

https://stackapps.com/questions/10634/hide-the-newly-introduced-homepage-widgets

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I blocked it too, made me cringe. The good news is that you can also block the blog now, hooray!

Err actually you can only block the blog from stackoverflow.com, not while vising a specific page or you'll block meta announcements too. And the HNQ is still there while visiting a specific page. Now if anyone could explain to me what good these changes did...

This redesign looks awful on desktop, removes features that I use regularly, adds visuals I don't want on my home page, and makes the interface look both sparse and crowded, somehow. Please revert to the previous version

Where is my full sidebar list of watched tags? I had access to all my tags of interest in one place, all visible at once. Now we are left with a stupid scroll list that doesn't even show 3 lines of tags at once. Total garbage. Please fire your UI/UX team.

What did you do to take away my watched tags but keep useless information around? I keep a browser window on the right half of a 1440p monitor, and I had my watched tags at the top, with useless information. Now I have useless information and no watched tags. FWIW, it could still all fit, I know this because it used to. Like a day ago.

Is there a way you make the link for the StackOverflow on the menubar (top-left next to hamburger) configurable in the user-profile? It would be very helpful to be able to remap it now to, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest or the like.

To add to the list of complaints: saved filters are gone and homepage was the main way I accessed them

Why nobody is fixing it? It is really not useful and I did not find any questions anymore simply by missing the highlight colors... what is going on here?

Since this change and the removal of the HNQ I was not on any other SE page but SO (though it's becoming less and less) - which was for sure not the case until then.

I love how this gets overwhelmingly negative feedback, and it is just ignored. Why even post these requests for feedback if you aren't going to listen?

Why is the hot network questions being removed? I'd much rather have that than the overflow blog

Agree, I never read those blogs.

I really enjoy seeing a glimpse of the weird and wonderful questions on the other networks. It really helps promote networks I'd have never come across before.
The adverts could be moved to the left-hand side where there's already lots of free space. Although I'm sure most users are just adblocking anyway.

Yeah, now that most of the blog posts are about AI things I really do not care.

HNQ is definitely the most common thing which draws me into other networks, without it in the sidebar I'll view fewer total pages on the SE network for sure

Maybe they are putting the blog(s?) there to try to get us to read them. I never read them either. I won't read them if they are shoved down my throat like this. I love the HNQ feature! Removing it is an awful idea. They won't listen to us though.

The SE PMs seriously think users - any users newbie to experienced - would prefer a box with "Featured On Meta"/"Hot Meta Posts" to HNQ?  Wait, never mind that: They think it would drive more site traffic to have "Featured On Meta"/"Hot Meta Posts" instead of HNQ?  (If nothing else consider the rate of change in HNQ vs meta posts:  Which will be most often novel and new and create clicks?)

To be fair I have disabled HNQ (this can be done in settings) because it distracts me too much - which is just a testament to how effective it is! The blog is just an ad that I'll never click, especially since half of them are just ads anyway and the other half are vlogs

What?! Hot network questions is the reason I even know more than just Stack Overflow exists. I've learned so much from unrelated fields just being a wallflower. HNQ is orders of magnitude more helpful/useful than blogs which clearly people don't care about.

I take it this also means that the user setting to hide hot network questions now doesn't actually do anything?

I stopped caring that much about programming, but mainly visit SO for the HNQ.

HNQ was the only thing on the homepage that I used.

@MichaelW. HNQ is still visible on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ and tag pages, etc.

Now that HNQ is removed, I have no reason to visit the SO homepage ever again.

HNQ is pretty much my main reason for visiting the site, as there's always some interesting/entertaining things.  It's even driven me to join up to some of the other sites so I can delve in and answer things.  I really, really think you should reconsider this one!

@EllieK I wouldn't mind seeing blog posts emphasized, if they were actually blog posts.  Instead they're videos masquerading as blogs, and that frustrates me to no end.  I have no interest in watching a video.

@MarkRotteveel Which seems like entirely the wrong place to put it. It's a homepage feature, full stop.

@GalacticCowboy It has always been available on all list pages, they now only removed it from the homepage. I'm not agreeing with that choice, I'm just saying that the feature still exists elsewhere.

Instead of going automatically to StackOverflow you can instead visit StackExchange, whose entire homepage is HNQ.

@RobinWhittleton sshhhh, if you remind them, it’ll be replaced with more ceo-trying-to-justify-existence crap before you can blink…

HNQ is what keeps me informed of the existence of more sites, that's why I know this is actually a family of 170 forums and not just this one, I even post in some other sites. It's outright crazy being removed from the homepage and present everywhere else. Even from a total $$$ point of view, that drives pageviews to other sites, so even if people eventually abandons SO, some other sites can still gets visits and activity. Removing it is a huge mistake.

+1 on this. I like to see what's going on on other site in one glance. Plus, it is so empty now ! THERE IS A HUGE 25% OF THE SCREEN NOT USED. PLEASE STOP WITH THIS KIND OF DESIGN. MY COMPUTER IS NOT A PHONE

HNQ. Click add bookmark in browser.

the fact that HNQ still exists on the other stack homepages makes this change even worse. The discontinuity here is a new world record.

Another step towards making Stack Overflow the only site, and getting rid of all others. This is wise, I must admit. They just let the sites die naturally as result of lack in avid users, as SE it well aware most of those arrive from Stack Overflow, initially, following some interesting question they notice in the HNQ sidebar.

I'm OK with the blogs being removed from the sidebar; I can always get to them from the Overflow newsletter if that feature is gone from the home page. But, please, keep the HNQ section. I quite often check that out to see if there's anything interesting, which there quite often is.

Questions and answers are the actual content. The reputation graph is nice, but this is really something for the user profile. The badge progress is pretty meh. The list of watched tags is important and useful, but I think you really could do more with that and integrate it better into the site. It feels out of place at the top there.
Your screenshots also don't show how this will appear for a typical user as they don't show the viewport but the entire page. There is a lot less vertical space on a typical screen, and this means that the widgets at the top will push the actual content lower and off-screen.
As a purely personal opinion, I don't want the site to talk to me. The welcome at the top is superfluous.

Frankly I find the welcome message creepy. It's mostly spammers and Twitter trolls that like to try to address me by name. Welcome back, Colleen. Colleen, have you done any reviews lately? Hey Colleen, there are new posts in your watched tags! Shut up already. I might change my profile name to dumbass so the   automated attempts to make me feel connected will at least make me laugh.

Hey "dumbass", that's unironically a great idea. I think I'll change my username to "dude", although I guess "icedwater" is also fine.

To be honest, I think the widget area would be good if you can collapse it.

The badge progress is designed to keep users contributing for the feeling of working towards a reward.

@CriticizingSEisbannable Because what we need is more people posting because they're addicted! That will surely improve the site.

@jpmc26 that is the reason stack overflow is popular. People wouldn't write answers if they didn't get brownie points for doing so.

Also, why does it say "welcome back"?? I was never away, 99% of the time I look at that page. And yes, the greeting is pointless.

Yeah... Welcome back is both creepy and domineering the whole page. Watched tags on top is good only if you have few of them. Side position was better as they can freely expand by height there.

@ColleenV Sorry, taken.

@dumbass Dang it. Welcome back dumbass47732! doesn't hit the same way and I don't like to be a copycat:)

You could still try something like “man, we are reinstating Monica”…

@dumbass Microsoft just patted me on the head and said "Nice job!" after I enabled desktop notifications for Teams in my browser. I am irrationally enraged by it. I turned that setting on, and by God I'll turn it off if you abuse it MS! Are there people that find automated patronizing affirmations a happy thing? Am I just damaged from being a latchkey kid?

"The list of watched tags is important and useful, but I think you really could do more with that and integrate it better into the site. It feels out of place at the top there." Perhaps in the right sidebar, where it used to be?

The list of watched tags is the worst redesign ever made to SO. I guess it depends on how you use the site, but for me, the homepage is now USELESS! Give me back my full list of watched tags and not that utterly stupid scroll list that show two AND A HALF lines of tags. Total fail once again.

@CriticizingSEisbannable SO became popular because they advertised a model that was designed to curate quality content and filter out trash, and this resulted in a lot of great content by competent people. They have since abandoned that model and are riding on the inertia against getting a competitor going.

@ColleenV I find your reaction to be entirely rational. That pop up is there to trigger your reward psychology, and the people who designed it knew exactly what they were doing and did it to get more people to use their product. And you understand that. You are fully aware of an attempt to manipulate you in an insidious manner. You should be angry about that.

Please do not greet me by name.  You don't know me.  The message has no impact on whether I feel welcome or not.  It wastes precious screen real estate.
Please let me eliminate those top widgets for myself.  Ideally, don't foist them onto anyone.  The gamification aspects of Stack Overflow were once pretty important, and they still serve a role, but they also (unintentionally) incentivize quite a bit of less-than-great content, so it would be best not to over-emphasize them.  The essence of rep changes and badges are all already in the top status bar.  The widgets are already available on the user pages for people who are interested.
And, of course, the widgets waste precious screen real estate.
It's not just the loss of one or two fewer questions above the fold.  It's the deemphasis on what's important:  questions about software development.
Remember the old blog posts by Joel Spolsky?  The point of the home page was to make it immediately obvious what the site is about.  Seeing the question titles (hell, even the name Stack Overflow) makes it instantly obvious to a software developers that this is the right place.  (It also makes it clear to non-developers that this probably isn't the place to ask for help with a computer issue.)  Putting a too-familiar greeting and gamification widgets above the questions dilutes that signal.
Remember how browsers broke the GUI models in order to make their interfaces as minimal as possible?  Essential functionality was jammed up onto the window's title bar, the menu bar was eliminated, the search box was unified with the URL box, seldom-used buttons were hidden by default, bookmarks were relegated to popup menus, and status bars became ephemeral.  This was all about de-emphasizing the browser in order to make way for as much of the content as possible.
Treat the home page the same way:  Show only the most essential non-content navigation and status UI in a compact, efficient, and usable way, and then let the site be about the content.
The gamification is not the content.  It's a feature that tries to incentivize the creation and curation of good content.
Please do not automatically "personalize" the feed.  I've never seen this done well.  Recommendation engines can assist with discovery of relevant content, but they should never be a gatekeeper.
Seeing the same feed as everyone else is a feature.  Trends in the types of questions appearing in the feed are more telling (and timely) about what's new, what's old, and what are other developers working on and struggling with than the SO developer surveys.
When I go to a news site's home page, I don't want or expect to see headlines of articles some algorithm thinks I'm most likely to read.  I want to see which news stories the editorial staff thinks are most important for everyone to see.  (If the site has other pages for tailored content, fine, but the common-for-everyone home page is a feature.)
SE seems weirdly obsessed with building "community" among its users.  I don't understand this desire, but I'm happy to leverage it.  So consider this:  Shared cultural experiences build a sense of community.  If each user exists in a unique filter bubble, then there's no common experience to bond them together.
Please do allow me to have a longer tag watch list.  There are several topics I'd love to see highlighted, but there's been a pretty low limit on the number of tags you can watch (like 25?), which has forced me to make some painful cuts.

The badges and reputation progress just seems so entirely useless to me. Like what do I care what my reputation is over time? And badges, what can I even do with them? If they were physical then yeah, I guess, but they're basically just records in a database and entirely meaningless to me

@JaDa Badges and progress do matter. But once you get to a certain level (varies by person as to what that level is) most people don't want to see anything except a single total # unless they specifically want to think about it all for some reason. And then all they have to do is click into their profile and they can look at the details.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact:  Even for those who find value in reputation and badges, these widgets don't actually provide anything useful.  The tiny plot of reputation over time doesn't convey much and isn't as motivating as a green "+10" floating by your visible-on-every-page rep on the status bar.  A widget that tracks your progress toward one specific badge (without even telling you what that badge represents) can be just as demotivating as motivating.  Meanwhile, the amount of prime home page screen real estate devoted to these is hugely disproportionate to what's actually important.

October 28th; The day Stack Overflow became even less user-friendly.

Please compare these 2 images side by side




Welcome back, 0stone0

I was here 2 minutes ago, no need to welcome me back?


Reputation, badges and tags

Thanks for showing me where I can earn reputation, as somebody with 42k rep, I had no idea
Thanks for showing me my watched tags. Even tho I've picked those myself, I really need to be reminded of those starting with a, b or c every time I open the homepage
In general, this kind of information should not block me from seeing the questions I came for. That information should be on the side (desktop) or on your profile.


Where did the bountied, hot etc buttons go?

'Overflow Blog' & 'Meta Posts'

Buttons are missing an outline/color, impossible to distinguish
Where did the Overflow Blog icons go?
Where did the Hot Meta Posts votes  go?


Mobile screen became these 3 blocks (My specific phone shows only 1 question without scrolling):




I really hope this is an early a/b test and not the actual final design.

I don’t even see that one question on mobile.

I'd like to chime in to describe my first experience with this new design: I opened the page, scrolled down, noticed that the hot network questions were gone, tried to adblock the gigantic useless (for me) widgets, noticed that they reappeared when I reloaded the page, and subsequently changed my bookmark to stackoverflow.com/questions, which still shows me exactly what I want to see. Who knows, maybe the new design will help with user activation, but for me that was just a bad time.

100% agree, if I hadn't seen this answer, I would've written it myself. On my list there's also 6. missing HNQ and 7. no highlight for questions with a watched tag.

Oee nice breakpoints! Graphic design is my passion

Agreed the mobile view is less than ideal is bad, we are working on a fix for that. I think we are gonna condense them all into one widget that you can scroll through and drop the welcome message and/or change the cadence to be pretty infrequent. Up in the air at the moment.

Then please allow us to disable the widget all together. Combining it into 1 makes it better, but does not solve the issue.

OMG I had not looked at the mobile appearance. That's a major screw-up. Somebody was not testing well.

Regarding your point 2, second bullet, I use the watched tags to quickly navigate to the specific tag pages or tag-filters I'm interested in, but the old location to the right was much better.

If reducing the number of visible widgets from 3 to 1 is an improvement, imagine how much better reducing it from 3 to 0 would be.

@SpencerG Working on a fix? Why don't you just bin all that garbage and bring back the old design which was just fine?!

@SpencerG please just revert back to the old page instead of trying to polish the turd you released in a mvp state.

 Welcome back, Marco Bonelli

This has to be one of, if not the worst UI/UX update you guys have ever forced on to us. It's a big nope for me, and I'm probably going to repeat things that have already been said, but let me explain what I don't like:

I don't know why anyone would "welcome" you saying your full name. A lot of people use their full name on their SO profile and this is what happens. Reading "Welcome back, Marco Bonelli" feels off. It feels eerie. Secondly, why is this thing welcoming me every single time I browse to the homepage? I've been here 2 seconds ago, what is the "welcome" for? No other website I use does this. Heck, I wouldn't even know why would a website welcome you at all.
Reputation and badge progress is something I really do not care about that much, and it's already in my profile, where I would expect it to be. Putting it in my face at the top of the homepage just makes it annoying. It makes it look like a passive-aggressive reminder that I need to somehow improve the metric and that's the most important thing that I need to care about. It delivers the wrong message. Reputation is also visible at the top in the status bar, where it's always been, so this is also redundant.
Watched tags used to be nicely displayed in the side bar and now they are compressed down into a tiny amount of space with a scrollbar where I cannot even see 3 full rows of them. Come on... how can anyone in their right mind think that this is an improvement?
The whole right sidebar now feels useless. Where did my custom filters go? Custom filters are the most helpful tool I use on a daily basis to find questions to answer. I would definitely rather have those than a duplicated reputation counter and a useless badge progress bar. Thankfully they are still in the sidebar in the /questions page (which by the way I am making my new homepage at this point).
I do not use SO on mobile that much (thankfully), but as others have pointed out, this new banner thing now fills the entirety of the browser viewport and you have to scroll one full page to get to what you actually want to see, i.e., the questions. If this isn't a big UI/UX failure I don't know what it is.

These were just 5 points off the top of my head. I am sure if I keep staring at this new homepage design I could come up with even more, but I really don't want to look at it that much. I'll simply redirect stackoverflow.com to stackoverflow.com/questions with a user script and call it a day for now.

"Maybe I am remembering incorrectly, but weren't custom filters on the homepage too?" Yes, on the right sidebar: https://i.sstatic.net/rq68jakZ.png

@VLAZ glad to see I wasn't going insane :'). Thanks, updated my point above.

"glad to see I wasn't going insane" let's not be so hasty in declaring sanity :P

I entirely agree with your point 1; on top of that, I really hate (hate!) the use of that waving hand icon

Seconding the missing Custom Filters box!  That's how I find (found, apparently?) questions to look at!

Thank you for pointing out that https://stackoverflow.com/questions still has the old sidebar!

The fact I now have to open a random (likely irrelevant) question, just to get to my custom filter is already frustrating me greatly...

@ThomA careful doing that, you're going to mess up the suggestions on the new amazing homepage /s

Good, it'll further evidence how s**t the design is, @MarcoBonelli . I'm never using that page other than to navigate away from said page.

"why is this thing welcoming me every single time I browse to the homepage?" - because this site stopped being about content and expertise long ago, now it's all about fluff and happy vibes and being welcoming. As "being welcoming" doesn't exactly translate well into useful technical requirements for website development, it seems like it was just taken literally...

Let me tell you a couple of stories.

I got sent a link to Amazon by a friend. It was accompanied with a message like "look what they sell, lol". It was a door. A front door, that you can order. It was amusing - I looked at it for 30 seconds, smiled, and closed the tab.
For the next few weeks Amazon was recommending me front doors when I visited the front page. I do not want front doors, I looked at one. But Amazon did not distinguish between what I looked and what I actually want.

A very similar story. But it was eBay and a toilet. Somebody sent me a message like "look what they sell, lol" and a link. Again, for a while (maybe only a week or two) I would get suggestions for toilets.
Again, eBay did not differentiate between what I looked and what I want.


I will also let you in on not-so-much a secret. This happens all the time. Many platforms do this. YouTube is another example. A lot of platforms conflate "user visited page for X" with "user wants X". I have found that basically all sites/services/applications that try to recommend me stuff are just wrong. Or maybe I am supposed to commit to purse everything if I have ever looked at it. But I do not want to.
To bring it back to this topic:

This will be a feed of questions that are curated for you. We will start with the existing logic that is on the homepage today. For a v2 we are exploring if we can do something a bit more personalized based on your viewing history and watched tags. You will have the option to customize this to some extent by adjusting your watched/ignored tags.

(emphasis mine)
The "Interesting" Stack Overflow already fails for me.
I visit a lot of questions that I otherwise have no interest in other than maybe close vote or edit the question. I am completely certain that is neither what you thought about nor will be something you implement in your algorithm to present questions for me. Most likely, the algorithm you have in mind is that if I have visited a question with tag [x] I will get more questions from the same tag. But it will not check if:

I opened the question because it had tag [y] on it and I wanted to remove it.
Or maybe I visited because I wanted to edit the wording - like a typo in the title.
Or because somebody posted spam in the answers and I went to flag it.

Come to think about it, I doubt it will even check if I visited a question to flag it as spam.


Or because I visited from a review queue.
Or I visited because I checked some user's contributions.

And so on. I would be surprised if your intention is to provide me questions with wrong tags and with typos and so on as interesting for me to open and edit or do whatever other actions.
Watched/ignored tags are too crude of tools to control this. I do not want to ignore all tags I do not want to see in my feed. I want to ignore tags for a reason that is my own, not just to Appease The Algorithm™. Same with watching.

it also... will tend to pigeonhole people into areas and not really organically help them explore past that. I like the current interesting tab, because for me it's a relatively broad set of results, some that are relevant to my watched tags and many others that aren't, but it's what i'm looking for: a broad set of questions. If i wanted something tailored to a particular type of question... we have custom filters for that.

@KevinB yes, the pidgeonholing is something I've also experienced with other platforms. When they try to suggest me stuff but also feed off on their suggestions, then form this magic inescapable circle that locks itself because it only suggests stuff that were similar to other suggestions. YouTube and music apps do this all the time. You'd start some "randomised" playlist and it just gives you the same stuff. YouTube in particular used to be really bad (probably still is) - you play some song, it continues with similar ones and narrows the range until it plays the same 3 songs over and over.

no, the users are wrong. you're supposed to open anything you don't want the machine to think you want more of in an incognito window (I'm joking around, but I wish I was only joking about this)

I think we are pretty receptive to feedback on this point. If you have different data points or site behavior you think we should incorporate, do let me know, and I can bring it up.

@SpencerG I've shared my experience. That was the data point I wanted you to consider. Because it seems nobody who does suggestion systems does that. The application I use to order fast food is even mocking me with this - if I open it, I get suggestions for "Since you ordered salads" which...I really should be ordering instead of the pizzas and burgers I actually order. But the suggestion algorithm seems to believe that since I've ordered from places that contain salads (which is most places. As side dishes), then it will suggest me this category.

I'd be amazed if whatever you were thinking of didn't end up doing something similar. "Seems you've been looking at questions for arrays - here are other questions for arrays for languages you don't know". The behaviour I'd want to avoid is is that one. I feel I've given more than enough examples where that's wrong.

@VLAZ: For that, they would do well to focus recommendations on those questions which share "tags which many people have in favorite tags list".  Languages and frameworks will tend to be favorited a lot.  Cross-cutting primitives like arrays won't be favorited by anyone.  Cross-cutting research level stuff (neural-networks perhaps) will be favorited somewhere in between.

Instead of views, I think substantial interactions (e.g. answering a question) might be a better input signal.

Spot on for review queues! Just because the next random question involved Cobol, doesn't mean I want to look at any Cobol questions.

Are these widgets going to be in a container we can target all at once? I'm definitely going to want to remove them, they serve no purpose for me.
My account name and rep is at the top of the page, increases and decreases are on the trophy icon at the top, and I'm not chasing badges. :shrug:
Watched tags are somewhat important on this page, given this is where you'd generally want to see it, but they're not important enough to be at the top of the page. The right side bar is fine for that. (where are ignored tags? that used to be in the side bar too.) Also... with watched tags up here we can't even remove this section without losing functionality or adding userscripts. :(

I generally think this is an improvement for newer users and users who are still actively chasing badges/rep/etc, but... it's just more stuff to scroll past every time I open the page. Even just adding an X that closes it out and duplicating the watched tags widget on the right column where it was would be fine.

Will be working on a userscript to hide the widgets once they roll out... Shouldn't take more than 15 minutes or so :)

@M-- I just right click and "Block Element" using an ad blocker. Though in this case, one would have to block the watched tags too.

Yea, that's my annoyance. i don't want a user script, i want to just block with with my browser... but if i do that with these elements i lose watched tags

@M-- while you're at it, could you also remove the "max-width" attribute from the content pane? xD  I don't know what's the idea behind that, but it always bothered me to have like 800px worth of dead space left and right...

@QBrute that's already done: https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/StackExchangeWiderMode.user.js

Even though I'm low-key chasing badges, I don't really need to see the widget up top and in my face. I would like to see my watched and blocked tags back, though, as a widget or otherwise.

The current proposed design seems noisy, and on wide screens, it feels like you're overloading the vertical space available, and ignoring the horizontal space. We'd note that we already have a sticky top bar and now I'd guesstimate about a fifth of a front page is taken up by widgets. I suspect its an attempt to play up the gamification aspects of the page.
Did y'all consider adding these to the right side, or somewhere else less critical?

It would be good to know how many questions appear above the fold on the old vs new design for a typical screen height. And consider if that can be improved.

Doing a rough estimation based on the screenshot size and my 1080p viewport, it's not as big a difference as I first expected, only about 1 or two questions depending on how you count. I get about 7 question "stubs" on the current home page (since the body snippet is hidden there right now), and 6 on the current /questions page; the new home page screenshot, which now includes body excerpts like the questions page, still gives me 5, so it only sacrifices about 1 question.

I have always wondered why only the middle half of the screen is used for content here on SO, wouldn't it be better to use all the screen? We don't have VGA screens anymore.

as I understand, there's a design rule that there's a maximum optimum line length - though I'm half certain it very much depends on quite a few factors. In that respect I really like how wikipedia does it, with basically almost full control over those settings.

@JourneymanGeek Multiple columns FTW.

This sucks.
It eats up too much space at the top of the screen, presents information I don't need to see every minute (rep and badges, which I could already see in the page header), badge progress (which if I cared about seeing, I could see in my profile), and watched tags (which were fine where they were on the right sidebar), but only a small subset of the tags I watch. (I can't figure out the logic used to determine that subset, either. At least one of them is a tag that almost never sees any activity, and it's among whatever random tags were selected.)
It also seems to filter questions out that I didn't choose to have filtered out. We had the ignored tags functionality for that purpose.
I don't see a single thing that this UI change improves, and a whole lot that it spoils. The first thing I did when I saw it had been rolled out was to go to the Settings in my profile to see if it could be disabled, and was extremely disappointed (read that as pissed off) that I couldn't.

After 15 years and 300k rep, thousands of visited days, thousands of answers, through controversy and churn, I've never actually encountered a change that made me just close the tab and think "ok, that's just too hard to bother with." Until today. What the heck?
I've been long used to the fact the "interesting questions" list only mildly intersects my interests. For years, I just skim for the highlighted questions that I actually care about because I set a tag to say I care about them. And now...that's gone? Less than 10% of the questions on the main page are even tangentially interesting to me, and zero are interesting enough to open. None are highlighted so I have to look at every one of them. And the answer to that is "no, I'm not going to do that."
I really don't care what you do with the page. I don't care how much you churn it and rearrange it and put unneeded graphs at the top. It's fine. Web designers get paid to change things. But you've made it impossible to find questions I care about, which is all I've ever cared about.
I don't know what your criteria was for this change. My guess is that it's AI-centric, based on the assumption that your algorithms know what I want. They've never known very well, but at least I could get to the tags I subscribed to. Without that, I don't know how I'm supposed to use this site anymore.

As people rightfully noted, you can go to the "questions" page and see the old page, before these changes. If you use bookmarks, just change the link in the bookmark. If you (like me) don't, tough luck.

@anatolyg Thank you. That feels less targeted than it used to be. Often it now has zero tags I follow. I feel it used to be at least ~25% (it's never been very good). But maybe I'm deceiving myself about how much my tags ever influenced that page, and I was just lucky then, less lucky since this deployed. The vast majority of things I respond to are in the Swift/iOS worlds, which are a small corner of SO. I suspect that "the most common user, who is a web dev" is driving the AI.

The Questions page isn't the same as the old home page and shows all questions. There's no way to get the old home page back, the one that showed mostly the questions we cared about.

I've been able to recreate what I want with a custom filter. You can select "Sorted by Recent Activity" and then "Tagged with My watched tags" and it'll be pretty good. It's hard to make a bookmark to it (since the result hard-codes all your tags), and I can't make it my default screen, but it does make SO usable. (That I must do so much work to make SO usable is its own discussion....)

The widgets should not push all questions below the fold on smaller screens. This is what the homepage looks like on my phone now:

Not a single question is visible. The widgets are crowding out all the space and all question have been pushed below the fold. If the screen isn't big enough to display the widgets on a single row at the top, it probably isn't big enough to display them at all, and it would be better to hide them than let them flow.

Yup, we are considering some options to fix this, but we are undecided. Not a great experience though.

In addition to the various reasons mentioned in other answers why the greeting and hand waiving isn't welcome, please note that a hand with splayed fingers is a rude gesture in certain cultures (or at least in mine):


Please don't insult me every time I visit the site. Not only is this exactly the kind of noise we strive not to have here, it is actively insulting your users or, at least, your Greek users. Please don't. If you absolutely must have this rather pointless thing, at the very least make the fingers be close together and not spread out.

(Somewhat tangential) To me the SE logo looks like a waving hand emoji. Looking at the historic designs for Apple; iOS 4 had one similar to the SE icon/mountza, where iOS 5 changed to have the fingers not spread out. Would you find the iOS 5+ icons to be offensive?

No, not at all @Peilonrayz. The spread fingers are essential to making it offensive. So the iOS 4 one, with the fingers spread, immediately registers as a mountza to me, while the 5+ ones with the fingers together do not. The 4.0 actually looks like it was specifically designed to look like the rude gesture. I imagine it wasn't, but it's that close.

The same icon (minus maybe a motion line or two) has been used for years on SE. What type of "welcome" have you been giving new users exactly :p?

Is the hand supposed to be blue in dark mode? o_O

Interesting. Definitely was not something we were aware of. Will bring it up with this team.

Thanks, @SpencerG. To be clear, it is COMPLETELY understandable that the team didn't know it. Nobody expects y'all to be familiar with all hand gestures used by all cultures in the world.

@SpencerG seeing only uninteresting questions in the last few days does make me fill a bit ... double-facepalmed. Like someone doesn't care what I want to see, only what they want answered

I had no idea this was offensive in some cultures but damn, what a total fail this redesign is from A to Z. This just shows how thoughtful they were with the whole project.

To be fair, @MrUpsidown, that wavy hand is relatively common and it isn't reasonable to expect folks to be aware of what might be offensive in which country.

@terdon what "folks" are you talking about? The whole Stackoverflow UI/UX team? How about the V sign? You do know it has different meanings (to different people) depending on the side of the hand that you show? They could have done a bit of research really. It's like if you launch a new brand and realize afterwards that it has a terrible meaning in the 2nd most spoken language on earth...

@MrUpsidown a "bit" of research would likely have discosvered the V issue you mentioned since that is a British thing, so part of the anglosphere and anglo saxon culture, but I don't think it is reasonable for a dev team to be expected to know the minutiae of cultural differences that can be found across a few hundred countries. If, as seems likely, this is an exclusively Greek thing, Greece is a country of ~10 million people, it would be unreasonable for us to expect non Greeks to be aware of something like this. Dunno, I don't mind that they weren't aware, I would't have expected them to.

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm guessing you're Greek from your name. Out of curiosity, do you also interpret this hand as a mountza?

@terdon Fair enough, but anyway nobody needed that hand and welcome message in the first place so the solution sounds easy enough...

@terdon I was being polite about how annoying the new design is, and how it seems the company is trying to push us to "work" on questions they care about. So yeah, while at first it seemed funny, it feels worse every day

@PanagiotisKanavos yes, it's awful, dds nothing useful and makes it harder to see the actual content. But I am wondering whether you, like me, perceive the waving hand as a literal μούντζα or not. Does it look like it's waving at you or like it is giving you a μούντζα?

I don't want curation. I know what I want to see, and how I like to use the site. I don't want you to curate questions "just for me" like all the other recommendation algorithms online that I don't want.
Also, please please do not remove the Hot Network Questions! OMG that would be awful. I would never know what was going on at other SEs.
Why do you have to make changes?! Please consider not making these changes?

To shortly cover some thing others have said: Welcome back is creepy and domineering the whole page, top widgets are not useful and occupy vertical space, tags would be better on the side under Featured on the Meta as they would have vertical space for expansion, Hot Network Questions should be there, too, whole page is just too white and looks like polar bears in snow storm.
One thing that was not mentioned by others is that for unregistered users new Home page is extremely unwelcoming.
If you come there from some Q/A you found by searching the Internet, you will get a popup asking you to fill some preferences like tags you are interested in. If you close that dialog, you will stay where you were which is confusing.
But the worst part is that if you start customization by adding tags and choosing theme (followed by unnecessarily long 5 second animation) you will be greeted by login screen. Why?
If you are going to force people to create account, then show them login screen first, and then customization process. There are many users that don't want to create account and setting preferences that you will not store in any other way (cookies) will leave them seriously annoyed. You have just removed Home page for all of them.

Ah, so they implemented the super hostile "Customize your experience! Great, thanks, now login to save it or you lose it all!"

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/400651/200898

@KevinB I never noticed that is was proposed... it is hard to keep track of every new feature announced... and it takes time to read everything carefully. And I don't have enough facepalms for everything that keeps coming our way...

So far i haven't been able to trigger it, so it might be an A/B test

@KevinB Lucky you... I am triggering it all the time when not logged in, so I guess that I am either very unlucky with A/B  testing, or this is something they stored in cookies.

Actually, it only triggers when you click the home link, not the logo. How you reached the site is irrelevant.

The homepage is now less useful to me with this new design. The new Watched Tags widget hides most of my watched tags behind a little scrollbar.
My primary activity when landing on the StackOverflow homepage was to click one of the tags in the Watched Tags widget in the sidebar, to see if there were any new questions in that tag. Then I would do the same thing again on another watched tag, and eventually go through several tags that I wanted to check for any new questions.
Now that experience is really janky because the list of watched tags is in a different location on the homepage than it is in all other pages, and I have to deal with this tiny scrollbar to try to get to the tag I want to click on.
At this point I'm just going to change the StackOverflow bookmark in my browser's toolbar to go to some other page than the home page, and I'm probably never going to go to the home page ever again.
This homepage change is a net negative for usability and usefulness.

Not only did you eliminate the highlight on questions with watched tags, you eliminated the eyeball icon on the tags themselves.  Now I have no way to know which questions I care about.  Which means I no longer have a reason to look at the question list.  I can't answer questions that I don't look at - congratulations.

I've seen this feedback a couple of times; thanks for sharing. Our intention with the interesting posts is that you should see your watched tags there more frequently. But I can understand that since it's less obvious, it means more work on your part to identify them.  We are in the process of discussing what we could do here.

@SpencerG:  just let users configure their own landing page.  I want X, Mark wants Y.  Why should you choose Z instead?

As a logged-in user, (and I'm aware I probably should have said this during the previous round of feedback instead of just now), at least for me, I'm realizing now that my feeling about a homepage for Stack Overflow is... I don't really need one. I don't want one either. I operate in different modes- only one mode at a time, and each mode already has a page(s) for it (none of which are the homepage). I have NAtOQ for finding non-answers, I have my profile page for seeing my own activities, and I have my custom filter pages to find things to answer. That's basically all I ever use now, and unless something dramatic changes (like becoming a mod or something), that's basically all I'll probably use for the foreseeable future. The only thing I'd need from a homepage is to contain links to those places (and even then, as a power user, I wouldn't use it- I'd just use my browser's omnibar and keyboard shortcut navigation once autocomplete there has initialized). The /questions page (and sort of almost every other page) already/also fulfills that role of being that hub for links. Of course, this is just my PoV. I'm just speaking for myself here.


Reputation Widget

New users will see the widget displayed at one reputation point with links to asking, answering, and editing.

Since you will incentivise new users to do those actions, do you plan any better onboarding for any of these? Or is some alternative planned that will reduce the pressure on the system and the community?
In particular, I am interested what steps you would take for the editing. The review queue is usually hovering around full and part of the reason is new users making trivial edits that are either not enough or should not have been made at all. If you tell users they can win reputation by editing, that will lead to:

New users editing more.
...if they succeed because the queue is always an issue
...and if they do a suggested edit, chances are it will not be one that should have been made

Overall, leading to frustration for new users (if they fail to submit their suggestions or have them rejected) and reviewers (it is just more of the usual).
From a comment by Ryan M:

Alternatively: are there plans to improve the throughput or efficacy of suggested edit review? Or plans to reduce its necessity, by, say, allowing users to earn editing privileges by submitting a certain number of useful edits?

While the suggested edit queue is, in my opinion, the biggest issue, it will still be good to know what you plan to do for answering. I suppose Staging Ground can be assumed to take care for asking.

Was the will there be onboarding training a serious question, because, we know there won’t be any training or guidance. This comment is slight parody to the fact, new users have almost no guidance, on any of the numerous features that have recently been added.

Well, asking, answering, and editing aren't new but it sounds like their attempts to provide guidance might be worse than useless

@SamB they aren't new, sure. But now they will be seen as goals. New users have been editing to gain rep and some have just been doing the bare minimum edits, like only adding minor punctuation. I don't expect anything new here - we'll just have the same. But more of it. Which will strain the suggested edit review queue even further and...there isn't much further you can stretch it.

Alternatively: are there plans to improve the throughput or efficacy of suggested edit review? Or plans to reduce its necessity, by, say, allowing users to earn editing privileges by submitting a certain number of useful edits?

@RyanM good point. I planned to ask for something similar but I seem to have forgotten in the process of writing this post. I added your question to the post.

Right now, in terms of onboarding, we are considering updating the tour page. We have discussed suggested edits internally but have not quite landed on what we think we can do there, but it has been a frequent topic of discussion while working on this particular project.

@SpencerG how much are visitors actually engaging with the tour?

"New users will see ... links to asking, editing, and answering."  So will old, high-rep users.

@canon I don't have the historical numbers off hand, but I know when we discussed it earlier this year, it was pretty low, to nobody's surprise. So I am interested to see how that changes with just making it more visible, but of course the tour needs some attention and I think its gonna get it. Not a guarantee at this stage though.

The one thing I use daily -- my custom filter link -- is now only available on questions.
WTF -- Can we at least have an option for selecting our landing page?
Things I DO NOT NEED TO SEE

Badges (Do not Care)
Reputation (Do not Care)
Watched Tags (I know these)

and yet there they are atop the page.
This helps who, exactly?
By all means, make it harder for me to find questions I might answer.

This helps our new users! We've gotten feedback from many users that they aren't aware of the game and how to play. This top row is intended to help get our newer users engaged. A reminder that this is our MVP. It is one homepage to fit all needs which is HARD. We hope to be able to put more time into customizing this page for everyone's unique needs in the future.

@piper "We hope to be able to put more time into customizing this page" -- in other words -- too bad, so sad, you just have to live with it.

@Piper If it's only useful for new users why force it on everyone?

I can appreciate the frustration. It doesn't serve what you want the homepage to do for you, and as you mentioned is making things harder. One thing, in my opinion, we did was communicate that this would be worked on in phases and that we would be focusing on the default first. I can appreciate that this is undesirable to some, but these widgets, in particular, draw attention to different actions that new users take to find the content they might want to see and directly expose them to the gamification aspect of the site.

@dbugger Not at all! We'll address it in the next version.

@Piper you are working so hard to serve new users, who a small percentage of the total and of whom an even smaller percentage stay to contribute, to the direct detriment of the primary contributors in the community. If this is indeed intended to serve new users, then why is it being pushed on everyone, without even an opt out, much less a filter to actually show it to new users?

@vbnet3d That is actually incorrect. Our new users are 4x the number of contributors the last few months and 8x the number of content creators. We simply did not have time to build out filters, opt outs, etc because of the deadline to get the test out before the holidays to accurately measure the impact. This does not mean they will never come.

@Piper I wasn't talking about raw new user data - I was talking about long-term retained contributing. Yes new users have higher raw contribution numbers because they tend to create an account to ask a few questions - but do they actually stick around to continue contributing, especially in the high quality answers realm? Past data suggests that they do not. Edit: If you didn't have time to build the feature out correctly it should have remained an optional A-B test.

The top questions view currently used as the front page is generally where I land, and I'm used to this workflow.
Would it be possible to keep the clean, 'common' top questions view, possibly as a questions page option?

This. Yes please

No, this is a bad idea.  Different users want different first pages.  Let the user specify the landing page that stackoverflow.com automatically switches to.

@user2554330 looks like https://xkcd.com/1172/ to me.

You forgot one of the most basic rules: if it ain't broken, don't fix it.
I'm not saying that there is nothing that can be improved about the https://stackoverflow.com/questions but this new home page addresses none of it; it's just a straight downgrade.
I'm not gonna list all the things that are wrong with the home page because there is already a lot of answers that do that comprehensively.
Instead, I'll tell my personal story.
I'm not a very active user, but there is a few topics that I have some knowledge of and that are not very popular. I try to keep eye on the questions there because on bad days I'm the only one to attempt answering them.
I have custom filters for that and whenever I visit the site and there is something new in there, I can notice the blue dot next to the filter name.
With this new home page I no longer see the custom filters. I leave the conclusion to your imagination.

If you're looking for something that really should be fixed, here is one:
I've just got a notification. Paraphrasing, it was something along the lines "You're upvoting only answers. Questions need some love too.".
I'm usually upvote both question and a few best answers, sometimes even only the question, so this wasn't a general statistic over a longer time. It looks like the algorithm noticed that the last 10 things I upvoted was only question and it freaked out, without considering that they were all answers for a single question that I've already voted at, so here is something for you to work on.

FYI, the "questions need some love too" message has been network-wide for many years. It doesn't actually do anything, just an annoying nag.

As far as the filters are concerned those are still available on /questions. But this first pass was about improving the homepage experience for new users. Its fair if you believe that was the incorrect place to start, but its ultimately where we landed. We are looking at v2 to bring more advanced functionality and customization that serves more experienced users.

@SpencerG If you want to know whether a change intended for new users is beneficial for new users, then A/B test it on new users.

After actually seeing it live:
The greeting is weird and a waste of space, at least make it a dismissible banner and ideally only if someone hasn't been seen for a while, though that might be even more annoying when it does pop up.
The widgets are nothing but an even more annoying waste of space that belong in the profile—where they already are and have been since their introduction—and at the least should be configurable (show/hide, type, order).
The "personalized" list doesn't have any more relevance to me than the /questions list. It seems like it's even less relevant, but I think that's just because it doesn't even distinguish favorite tags. WTF is that?
When I go to the homepage, I want to see the questions with the most recent activity, just like it always has been. That, btw, is going to be much more important on other, smaller sites that rely on a handful of active users keeping an eye on everything.
It's so annoying to keep having to go back and add /questions, I'm going to make sure to dedicate some more time to the iOS client I've been poking at here and there.

After mulling things over for a bit I think I'd summarize this update as forcing a pushy new-and-returning-user experience on the site's oldest and most active members every single time we come here. You're targeting the wrong people. And over the years, I've seen the company's receptivity to feedback wax and wane, but I've gotta say this redesign certainly seems like a new low for willingness to listen to your users.

tl;dr: Lots of information important to me as an experienced user is gone, in favor if uninteresting and irrelevant things probably catering to newcomers.

The greeting as well as the three top boxes are redundant and irrelevant to me. The greeting is more creepy than anything else (it reminds me that you are tracking me personally, even though that is, of course, crystal clear in principle), I do not care much about my badges, I am aware of my tags because I chose them, and the reputation (of which I'm vaguely aware anyway) is displayed already elsewhere. Prime GUI real estate is used for redundant or irrelevant information. What were you thinking?
With the hot network question list you eliminated even more information that is very relevant to me, perhaps more relevant than anything else on my "home page". You are hopefully aware that I open my home page never because I need an answer to a programming question (I use google to find such answers, here or elsewhere); I open it to distract me from work (cough), which is in your direct interest because it is one way of user engagement. I really like the variety of topics on the site — the hot question list is a main reason I come back to the site that often. It makes zero sense that I have to open an arbitrary question (in which I'm typically not interested) in order to see the hot question list.
Additionally, the central list of SO questions is (and has been for a while, I think)  vertically more spaced out than it used to be, additionally reducing information of actual interest.

I understand that you try to engage and retain new users. Some of this, like reputation and badge mechanics, may be less self-understood for new users. New users may also feel flattered about a personal greeting. I understand you want them to connect to the gamification aspect of the site. I respect that the site needs to generate revenue. Perhaps the new home page could be the default for new users while experienced users are presented with more concise information. Alternatively, a customization option would be nice, with the new design being the default. Because detecting any customization options needs experience most new users would keep the new design for a while, but experienced users could fill the page with more relevant content.
Addendum: Funny that I was never aware of the /questions URL/page that popped up in another comment thread; that is pretty much the old homepage, isn't it? Tag-matching questions highlighted, not much space wasted above, a bit of text with the title of each question, HNQ ... I could do without the "teams", "watched tags" and "collectives" side bar widgets but I can simply ignore them and scroll down, no prob.

With the HNQ, we removed it since it generally doesn't get a ton of traction, but it is still available on /questions on the sidebar. But granted that isn't a great place for it either.

As far as the feedback on the welcome message is concerned, we are reading everything being said about that and thinking about how we can improve it.

@SpencerG I suppose the idea is to make new users feel recognized and valued. "Hey, this site cares about me, they even remember my name, they are so friendly!" It has about the opposite effect to experienced users.

@SpencerG Is it true that the HNQ is not used much? It is my favorite pastime and questions on it get lots of views. (Of course, "lots" is relative, and you have, hopefully, the numbers. But I'm astonished.)

Its been a couple of months since I heard the number but something like less than 2% of SO users ever click on anything there in year. I could be off a bit here though. That being said we have been talking more broadly about network discovery on SO as of late so I wouldn't quite call it gone forever from the homepage yet. Obviously not helpful for someone who wants it there now though.

@SpencerG Considering that the space that used to be filled by HNQ is now filled by literally nothing, surely it couldn't hurt anything to leave it there for those who are interested.

@JohnMontgomery That space is supposed to be for the recently viewed posts feature, but we had to delay it a bit as we identified some last second items that needed to be considered for it. That is a fair point overall, though.

@SpencerG Maybe you should consider that that 2% of users are probably your most active users...

Just because people don't click on HNQ does not mean they don't read it. It is not that there will always be something interesting there worth clicking, but how useful it is having nothing at all there? No matter how small is percentage of users are using (clicking) it should still be fair number of people and it does not hurt having HNQ there.

2% of SO users are the ones you absolutely need to keep on the site, or there is no Stack Overflow. Remember that.

@SpencerG I'd highly encourage rethinking how you weight interaction with the HNQ, whatever flaws it may have. It's basically the main way within the site for people find out about the rest of the network. I don't know how many total HNQ links I've clicked on my time here, but that's how I found the four sites I moderate and the sites where I've answered over 2000 questions. Having it technically accessible in some other page isn't actually helpful because it's not a thing people necessarily go looking for, it's something that they stumble upon and you want them stumbling on it often.

@SpencerG do you have numbers on how many non-users use HNQ? I know a few.

Oct 28th update:
I generally find this update frustrating; I don't see how any of the concerns that were brought up here were addressed.
Watched Tags
The watched tags widget gains a scrollbar when there are more than 2 rows of tags; this was unnecessary with the old design. It's mostly "ok" on desktop (despite being a poor location for a widget of this style,) but on mobile there's no reason for the height of this widget to be limited... it's in a column anyway. Can this widget be replaced with something more relevant/purpose built for this location and put back where it belongs?
Question List
We lost the filters, as expected, and it's frustrating mostly. There's no harm in these headers existing and taking us to the appropriate /questions page for them. We also lost watched tag highlighting. The copy at the top of the list indicates that the selection of questions is based on viewing history and watched tags, but, what about ignored tags? it makes no mention of those. Do they get omitted as before or are they not relevant to this page anymore? Do they follow the settings in our profile for ignored tags? FWIW the first question returned for me was a question unrelated to anything i've viewed recently and not relevant to any of my watched tags. Maybe it shouldn't state what you're wanting the list to eventually be and instead describe the existing solution more accurately?
Blog/Featured Meta section
On your samples, there was no space in the blog section for icons. On what was released, there is space for icons but the icons don't exist. Can we bring back the icons and actually use them to indicate what kind of blog post it is?
Recently Viewed Posts
Where is it? I didn't really want it anyway but uh, it's missing? my right column is entirely empty... those three widgets up top would be much better over there.

Reputation Graph
The reputation widget in this location gains a little indicator when you earn rep... except... there's no way to dismiss it without leaving the page... guess I'm just gonna have a constant notification on my page now... Why can't it dismiss when i dismiss the other reputation gain notification in the top menu?


The blog section was a bug. We already have a fix for that coming. Agree that the scrolls bar with the watched tags is not ideal. The question list is almost unchanged from the previous homepage list for Top Questions. There have been some improvements and we are working on a few more.

The recently viewed posts is not quite ready for prime time, but should be in the very near future.

Interesting posts for you
How is this list generated? Most of the technologies on the list do not appear in my watched tags and filters. I have certainly never seen questions or answers with .net-core, electron, windows terminal, angular etc.

This is actually using the same logic that the old homepage was using! No changes. But if you have feedback on what you would like to see from a v02, this is a great place to share.

@Piper It claims to be "Based on your viewing history and watched tags", but that seems to be completely wrong. None of the 23 tags of the top 8 questions have ever been of any interest to me, I never watched them and likely never even viewed them. Instead it simply seems to be the most recently created/modified questions (and some staging ground questions for no apparent reason whatsoever).

@bademeister If you don't like the staging ground questions in your profile settings under preferences, you can remove them. Otherwise, as Piper said, the logic is the same as before. Granted we don't have a visual indicator calling out watched tags now.

@nocomment Thank you for your comment and reply. Yes, the description "Based on your viewing history and watched tags" suggests something that is not.

@SpencerG But the description is "Based on your viewing history and watched tags".

@Bademeister Correct, its not really accurate at this stage. Though, my understanding is that we are pretty close to completing that part.

@SpencerG Well, then please put that text there when that part is completed. Not before.

@Piper If this is the "same logic", then it is broken, because the old logic filtered the questions by tag. Now I get questions that are completely wrong, because none of the tags match.

Is the "Custom filters" widget on this new design? I don't see it anywhere. If not, please add it back - the only thing I really do on the homepage right now is click a custom filter so I can start answering/moderating questions.

@trincot you should still be able to access the custom filters on the /questions page

@VLAZ, thank you! Relieved it is still there.

Yeah, looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions still has the old homepage sidebar

Badges?  We don't need no stinking badges!
Seriously, I don't care about badges one bit.  Making them the centerpiece of these changes seems misguided to me.

bug
As mentioned by others, the top half of the front page is almost entirely a waste of space... but now it is entirely a waste of space, as the "watched tags" widget has entirely disappeared.

BTW, it would be nice if users could disable the new design from their profile options while you're still iterating. Yeah, I know, you're gonna roll out the new design no matter how people feel about it... but please give us a little longer with the older and more usable version.

Given that SE is capable of A/B testing changes, it isn't too far fetched to expect them to allow opting into new features. Yes, it's probably not zero work to get there. But it also shouldn't be an insurmountable obstacle. The amount of features that get released and bork the site in various ways is too damn high. Moreover, even users who want to opt-into beta testing might find use to switch and opt-out to verify functionality is the same before and after.

A/B tests only give statitistically useful results for users who didn't choose one or the other. But an opt-out for people who have already been put in the B group seems like it should give some useful data (i.e. these people consider this change to be worse).

@kaya3 I don't think VLAZ is talking about actual A/B testing here, but the infrastructure needed to A/B test is almost exactly the same as for a feature that users can opt in/out of, the only difference is the condition is (approximately) random for A/B tests and a user setting for a opt-in feature.

@cafce25 Sure. But specifically for features that are currently undergoing A/B testing, it's expected that users can't toggle those features for themselves.

I am not able to duplicate the missing tags widget on Chrome or Firefox. What browser are you on?

@SpencerG It occurs with both Brave and Edge (both for Windows).

@SpencerG ...and with Firefox. Can't test with Chrome, due to privacy issues.

Thank you, I will pass this along.

The Watched tags are missing for me too. This appears to have to do with my screen resolution (I'm at 1280x1024). I can see the Watched tags again if i use the browser developer tools and use the icon where you can view the site at various screen sizes for responsiveness and change to a higher (or lower) resolution. If I check the css, one of the divs the Watched tags are in gets hidden with this css: @media (max-width: 1280px) and (min-width: 906px) {     .right-widget.svelte-1shgxe0 {         display: none;     } }

@Marleen Well-spotted, the box comes back for me too if I change the screen size.

Let me give you an example of how useless that reputation graph is.

The last answer I posted was in 2019, before this graph even starts. My last question was even longer ago in 2018.
The reason I continue to gain reputation at such an alarming rate with no posts is because I did my damnedest to post quality content, and if this graph is any indication, I even succeeded a few times. People are still finding some of my posts useful 5 years later.
Stop trying to use psychology to manipulate people with meaningless rewards. Focus on creating a good product, which in your case means having great questions and answers. That means you need competent people to trust you, and the company threw that trust away 5 years ago for cash and political/social activism.

bug
The watched tags are now constrained into a small box which requires scrolling to view what I have there.
This also breaks navigation, as scrolling with the mouse wheel stops scrolling the page if the scrolling focus is shifted to the watched tags box, and instead scrolls its contents. This happens for me on Firefox simply by having the mouse in that column whilst scrolling.
I can't help but repeat that this change is not an improvement.

Thanks, just to confirm, when you move your cursor off the watched tags your page still scrolls normally?

The update makes it harder for me to use the site.

With my setup, which is 1920x1080 and 150% scaling (Windows), the new welcome & stuff looks like it occupies half the screen vertically.

Together with the menu and "Interesting posts..." title, this leaves space for 2 questions -- for reference, around 5.5 questions fit into view when I scroll down. I don't like that.

The "interesting" posts don't seem to respect my viewed tags. 99%+ of them are not interesting to me.

The "hot network questions" are gone. I was using these.

The gigantic added "welcome back" is not informative. I have only one account on the site, and I know I'm logged in. Well, I feel personally offended with this one. I see no reason at all to shout this back at me in a 1000px font, wasting space on a site dedicated to efficiently solving problems. Unprofessional at least, insulting if you are so inclined.

The reputation and the badge progress, to me, are features that change over months, not minutes. I don't see a reason to look at them on every visit.

Watched tags are nice to have, if they worked. Sadly, looks like they don't. Will they work again at some point? If not, I don't see the point... is it a tombstone advertising a dead feature? Anyway, at least on desktop, there was enough space for them on the right.


People tell I have to navigate to /questions now to enable some of the old features. I can do that, but I don't see why make the site harder to use, and in an annoying way.

Appreciate the feedback. I will share it with the team.

I also don't understand how /questions is supposed to be a replacement for the previous homepage, as it does not have "Top questions" but only "All questions", or explicitly tag filtered questions, which are both different.

Bug report: The loading skeleton for the top sections seem to be light even in dark theme.


Thanks will flag with the team.

It's ironic reading comments below the question that go:

Back-and-forth discussions in comments are very hard to follow due to the lack of threading.

Yeah exactly! Implementing threaded comments is the one thing out of all proposed changes that will actually improve the site in the real world. I think Stack Exchange might be the last site on the Internet which doesn't have this. And so for example our only forum for discussions is one which wasn't designed for discussions...
If I had a dollar for every time SO is changing the appearance of some irrelevant side bar... However, if the sidebar change means I can ad block the "blog" without blocking meta announcements, I'm all for it.

"Implementing threaded comments is the one thing out of all proposed changes that will actually improve the site in the real world. I think Stack Exchange might be the last site on the Internet which doesn't have this." it's actually worse because threaded comments exist. This is by using a userscript from 2011. The script was made by an employee at the time. Who more recently re-joined SE. The userscript is not perfect but SE had 13 years and the know-how of the author to do anything about it.

Showing me my recently viewed posts is not what I need. Could you replace that with posts where I was active (answered, edited, left a comment), if I've had any activities in some period of time? Preferably with a way to configure that period of time and which actions should be considered. Part of my workflow is to go to the "all actions" page in my profile (btw. that page is delivered very slowly) and check for reactions to my actions.

Just curious: for "check for reactions to my actions", wouldn't it be more efficient to "Follow" the posts where you did actions, so you get notified about reactions? That's what I do. What's the advantage of your way?

@nocomment Following posts creates more noise and is perpetual.

Meh. I'm following thousands of posts and noise is rarely an issue. Where it does become an issue, I unfollow. (But ok, our contexts and thus amount of noise, and what we consider noise, likely differ.)

For the watched tags component, I think that it might be more obvious for new users to turn the text "Customize your content by watching tags" into a link that lets you watch tags instead of having a grey gear that doesn't stand out that much.

bugtag-watchingstatus-completed
The new Watched Tag widget does not allow you to enter wildcards anymore with the asterisk *
For example, I tried to add the wildcard android* in the widget and all that was added was android, which is the first item on the auto-complete list:

Note, the webpack* tag was added normally from the Watched Tag widget on the side panel.
Similarly, if you try to add google*, it will add google-chrome instead, which is the first item on the auto-complete list.
And this is currently how the wildcards are expanded when used in a search.
For example, click on Questions -> More -> Unanswered (my tags):


In addition, it is possible to add the same tag multiple times and they will be displayed in the new widgets (however, on refreshing the page, the multiple tags disappear):

It appears that the logic here is different to the logic used in other places for adding tags. I wonder if this post is related in some way.

This might be by design, or the devs were unaware of this tag search logic. I certainly was not. I will bring it up.

@SpencerG I added a screenshot showing how the expanded wildcards are used in search. Tag expansion with wildcards like this is certainly useful, so I hope that this is not by design.

So, just to be clear, I understand. You want to be able to add Android* and then expect it to have you watch all of those on your watched list.

@SpencerG I believe that this is what actually happens at the moment. It is useful also for ignoring tags For example, wildcard expansion with  status*

@SpencerG also typing in that input for the tag search is very laggy, it slows down the entire page.

@SpencerG This new question is probably related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/432112/18595321 It reports problems with creating the C++ tag, so the problem seems to be connected with filtering of some special characters, namely + and *

@PeterJames, thank you. I brought it to their attention.

We were indeed unaware of this logic. Should be fixed now. Entering a * character in the textbox will now make the Enter key and Add button just add exactly what is written in the textbox and ignore the dropdown options

Why is the RSS feed link being removed?
Will the RSS feeds for sites continue to exist in general?
If they RSS same feeds from the homepage are to continue to exist, then will they remain serving the same content, or do you intend to change it, e.g., to that curated feed?

Very little use by our measurements so we don't want it to distract from actions most users will take. Yeah, we need to find a new place for it, that is still being decided; feel free to make suggestions.

I'm... confused at the idea that a single text link and RSS icon could in any way distract from the rest of the page.

@SpencerG Well, part of the reason it's not used is because it's here. And secondly, you don't to click it more than once or twice to import it in your RSS client. Also, sure - perhaps the RSS feed on the main page of SO is not really useful to much. I subscribe to RSS feeds for other websites because they may get, say, 10 posts a day. Rather than 10 posts a minute like on SO. And the 10 posts from SO are likely not going to even all be of interest to me. However, a good place for the feed is going to be consistent. Not different per site/page.

Like, the only suggestion I can give for an unobtrusive link is a the bottom of the page. Where the current link may as well be - it's at the bottom of the right pane. But it's also there on other pages. Breaking consistency seems like a worse idea. It detracts from the discoverability.


we wanted to be sure we came up with a strong default experience that would support all users.

You can't.
You can't support new askers, experienced askers and answerers on the same home page. It will be a home page that is only slightly useful to any user.

Defaults are hard! Reminder that this is just an MVP. We hope to be able to put more time into customizing this page for everyone's unique needs in the future.

I don't want this page. Please focus on one group of users on the homepage and create alternative pages for other groups to bookmark.

@Willeke We tried to clarify in this post and the previous one that we would focus on the default experience first. And we tried to acknowledge that wouldn't be great for everyone. I can understand that you don't like it and respect that position. I would argue that this does serve new users to better familiarize themselves with some basic aspects of the network and encourage them to explore the site more.

@SpencerG so if it's only useful for new users, why are you forcing the (undismissable) NUX on everyone?

Those widgets and welcome are wasting too much space.
I use these uBlock Origin rules to remove them:
! remove widgets
stackoverflow.com###widgets-container
! remove welcome
stackoverflow.com##div:has(>.spotWave)
! add "Ask question" button to the right
stackoverflow.com###content>div:first-child:style(flex-direction: row-reverse !important; justify-content: space-between !important;)



Thanks for the feedback! We hope to be able to put more time into customizing this page for everyone's unique needs in the future.

Thanks, I hate it
Please revert ASAP, not sure why anyone would think this is an improvement whatsoever.
But as the past few years showed that SE is more likely to double down on bad ideas instead of listening to the wishes of meta, here's a filter to remove the "welcome" banner and the three useless rep/badges/tags widgets with ublock origin (paste this into "my filters" on the ublock origin dashboard; no guarantee it doesn't break with the next update):
! 4 Nov 2024 https://stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com##.d-flex:has(svg.spotWave):not(:has(.s-btn))
stackoverflow.com###widgets-container

This version keeps the "Ask question" button around; if you don't care for that simply remove the :not part of the first filter to remove the whole outer div and save a bit more space.

I answer questions occasionally on StackOverflow, but am not, like, totally obsessed with doing so.  It's more of an opportunity thing than something I go looking to do. So, making recently active questions less visible will significantly decrease the probability that I answer any questions.
I find it counterintuitive that hiding new questions will increase engagement on average... but I guess y'all have already A/B tested to see that questions get more attention this way?  What's the science here?

Where are my ignored tags?
OK so my watched tags are now hidden up at the top, but where did my ignored tags go?
Unlike HNQ which has also disappeared, I'm not entirely sure how to find these via some other part of this UI maze....

(Also HNQ seems to have disappeared, which is how I actually end up on the rest of the SE sites -- while my employer will thank you for removing this "distraction", I find it irritating that I now need to do 3 clicks to find the part of the network that I find most useful in terms of discoverability.)
Thanks for not removing the "interesting" questions filter though. Pity it still shows staging ground.

Click the gear by "watched tags" then click the "ignored tags" tab

@wjandrea That somehow manages to be both a reasonable place for them, and impossible to find.

I agree with @DBS here. The gear icon makes me think "click to modify the settings for watched tags" not "click to see a completely unrelated set of tags".

You can remove Staging Ground questions from your feed by going to profile settings>preferences

HNQ was removed due to not a lot of activity, it is still available on /questions though. But we hear the feedback on people wanting it on their homepage so we will discuss it.

I've rarely used /questions, tbh, and don't really see the point of that page. I actually actively used SO for 4+ years before realizing that page existed. With the redesign, I'm manually navigating to the HNQ by going top bar hamburger (right most icon, idk what its real name is) > More Stack Exchange Communities > Click 'StackExchange' logo at top. Previously I'd just go to the SO homepage, scroll down a bit, and see what was trending across the network.


We are undecided on the percentage piece as nobody is going to care to know if you are # 18,567,283, but it is fun to know if you are in the top 2% or something similar.

Did you not stop calculating this rank information for all but 400 users?
I never paid attention to the information, however, since that was removed, it does indeed turn out that many users found it fun to know if they are in the top 2% or something similar. We have had a bunch of questions for where that information is gone.

We did, this would be separate from that.  Its still up for debate so don't quite know what form it will take, but I think we are leaning towards showing this if you are in the top 500 users that month or something like that.

For last June, 87897 users posted something on SO. Ignoring the other ways you can get rep, only showing it to the top 500 is only going to be relevant to less than 0.1% of the active user base, who probably know about the rep leagues. Its probably not worth implementing if you aren't able to roll it out to at least the top 10,000.

(By first approximation, the top 5% is roughly 5000 users)

While RSS isn't part of my SE workflow any more, it used to be an essential part of what I did as a new user. I used to use the equivalent of the recent questions feed as a quick way to skim through recent questions, even ones no longer on the front page as a new user .There's also some room for some potentially virtuous automation  - some smaller sites add a feed to chat for users to have another way to keep track of main site questions
I have 2 questions here

would the recent questions feed be discoverable somewhere else?
Will/is the feed going to continue being available ?


Let's put it this way:



So I haven't visited stack overflow often as of late (for good reason...) and without sounding like a complete prick, but which intern has touched the design again. I am lost as a (not anymore) regular visitor.
The home page looks ai generated: "Create a home page that welcomes the user, shows their stats and the questions that they might be interested in".
Where are the questions, the quick filters, custom filters, tags, hot network questions (I loved these the most).
I can't imagine a world where someone wants to be greeted every time they visit the page (which I can imagine is going to be less and less the more of these changes happen). Why is my reputation and badge process all of a sudden more important then the fact that we are here to spread and consume information. I am really at a loss for words at how incompetent these changes have been.
I've been reading through this post for a bit now to figure out what people their opinions are, and I am wondering if they are even being considered.
Really poor decisions.
If the problem was the fact that people were posting poor answers to questions, you guys managed to succeed. Cause it's an awful experience even finding a question to answer...

At least to me the lack of background colors in the side bar makes it feel more cluttered and more difficult to quickly parse.

Interesting. So, would you like some more color variation or defined borders to make it easier to scan?

@SpencerG Sorry for the late response.  I think the different background for headers and content made it easier for me to orient myself.  It also doesn't help that "Featured on Meta" and "Hot Meta Posts" are together in one box now.


Interesting Posts for You
[...]
This will be a feed of questions that are curated for you. We will start with the existing logic that is on the homepage today.

The current homepage has another four tabs:

Bountied (also available on the /questions page)
Hot (not available anywhere else?)
Week (not available anywhere else?)
Month (not available anywhere else?)

Will the content from those be available elsewhere? I personally do not use these (along side with the rest of the homepage) but I assume some users do.

Not on the homepage, but it will still exist on /questions

@SpencerG: I don't understand your response.  What is the homepage if not the Top Questions feed?

@SpencerG Just to confirm: Hot/Week/Month tabs are being moved to the /questions page?

If the questions page is something different than the home page, how does one get to it?  Is doesn't seem discoverable.

@AdrianMcCarthy https://i.sstatic.net/GPl1AoUQ.png

@VLAZ:  So, no, not discoverable.  I didn't even realize there was a menu over there.

@VLAZ I somehow wasn't aware of that link or page. Funny, isn't this what the "home page" used to look like? I mean, my profile, badges, rep and whatever is all accessible though the neat little icons on top...  I don't now what the homepage is for then, don't need it at all. Staff: You can do with it what you like, I will simply not use it.,

I find that the complete lack of color makes the homepage look all samey, bland, boring and sterile. With the lack of highlighting and background colors, there are no eye-catchers anymore to guide you to important content, and clearly distinguish different areas of content from one another. It's all white with a thin border from top to bottom.

For what it's worth, the only questions I am "interested in" in the meaning you are intending are the ones I search for or the ones I have watched a tag for. Either the questions I land on via google, which you can tell from cookies, or the ones I open via a results page after typing something into your search bar.
Keep the "interesting posts for you" list to questions that match those criteria and it might work OK. Also, why do you call them "posts" if they are all questions? If you're only going to show questions on this list, call it a list of questions. If you want to keep calling it a list of "posts", it should show answers, too. Which will be significantly more difficult to code for.

Is this permanent now?
Given the feedback in the answers, and no reponse from the staff in a month, wording in the question, I'm not sure what to think. Is this an experiment, or a permanent change now?

Ads and widgets on home screen
Chiming in t(w)o ad(d): I thought I had the reduce ads privilege already, why do I have the privilege of seeing two new ads on the homepage and even on the /questions page as well?

And how might I enable/disable the widgets on my screen, to see only the watched tags, perhaps?


I agree with some of the stuff that has already been brought up. Having stuff up at the top clutters things up and is just more stuff to scroll past. You've got the horizontal real estate (which currently still has lots of room to put more stuff in), why not use it for that stuff?
As far is the Watched Tags widget goes, I think ignored tags are just as important, so there should be one for that, too.
I also agree that rep and badges are best left on the profile page. If I really want to look at that, I can always go there.

This seems like essentially a "+1 I agree with X, Y, and Z" answer; if so, you should vote for the posts that you agree with, rather than posting a separate answer.

@RyanM I've done that. I posted this answer to make my opinions more apparent than mere votes would. And, note that I have also included a suggestion in the first paragraph that I didn't see in any of the other answers (i.e., make more use of the currently empty horizontal real estate).

I would like to see the Interesting tab by default but I don't need any of the other widgets. On days when I feel like points are fun to grab, I'll click through to my profile - otherwise I want to get straight to the questions.
Also, as I mentioned in a comment above, maybe lower the bar for folks to get the "reduce ads" privilege so that newbies who haven't got ad blockers set up don't need to waste time scrolling past.
On the flip side, I'm curious: what would S/O lose if nobody clicked on any ad, ever? How much of the current revenue is sponsorship?


Watched Tags Widget

The final widget we are launching will allow users to see what tags they are watching. This widget is the same regardless of the user's experience with the network. The gear icon in the widget will allow users to add more watched tags or ignore tags.

How will adding/removing either watched or ignored tag look?
How will the widget look if you have a lot of tags displayed in it, not just the one row that looks well on mockups?
Would you be able to control whether the ignored tags appear greyed out or hidden1?

1I am aware that on the homepage questions with ignored tags are always hidden. I assume that will remain the same. However, the setting is still relevant for other sections on the site.

I didn't share the screenshot of the workflow for adding/removing tags cause we have not finalized the design there, but the current iteration is mostly similar to the current Watched/Ignored tags component.  I will have to circle back on the logic for how many tags will display at the most.

Right now we are thinking 1-2 lines showing on the component potentially. Past that we need to think more on where/how to show a complete list.

@SpencerG for reference, this is what my ignored tags look when expanded. That's 14 rows. For, honestly, not that many tags. Two rows have 1 tag each, for example. If this shows on the top of the page, it'd be annoying if it pushes content down. At least in the current way it's displayed, which cannot be collapsed back to the initial display.

bug
Widgets on mobile are no longer centered:


For a before picture, please see my other answer,

It's hilarious that you now only see two questions on the home page before scrolling.


We will add a new recently viewed posts component beneath the ad spots, which, as you might guess, shows recent posts as well as the total number of votes answers and includes an option to follow the post.

This seems very far down on the page. Moving it to the left menu can mean way more people see and interact with it.

(Possible) bug report: the vertical alignment or spacing of the text for the buttons on the /questions/tagged page is off, even taking into account ascenders and descenders:


I am not sure I follow, they look normal to me?

@SpencerG There's more space below the text than above it. I see it, but it's not an extreme difference

Displaying the username large enough for it to be read by nearby people or show up in incidental video recordings without one expressly providing it is outright dangerous for some, unbelievably thoughtless to my privacy, and a tremendous turn-off to using the new front page regardless of what else it has

Your avatar and reputation have always been shown in the header, which are enough to identify you. It's fairly easy to scroll down the list of all users and find those around 18.5k. For reference, it took me about 45 seconds to find you by your reputation and avatar, doing a binary search through the page number.

To be clear, it's completely normal for sites to identify who is logged in, so that you can see if it is not your own account and log out, or see which of your multiple accounts you are currently using. If you have such privacy requirements that somebody knowing your Stack Overflow username is a risk, then you need to take precautions to ensure that you don't accidentally show or record your screen while visiting Stack Overflow, the same as you would any other site.

I'm not concerned with advanced users (or really any users of StackOverlfow) who might have many ways to identify me or others, and the header itself is easily removed - rather I'm concerned with bad actors who are not a member of the site and not technical people who aim to harm users due to their own evilness - additionally, my personal reaction to seeing the banner was disgust

I'm not keen on the banner either, but in terms of privacy: If someone can see your screen then that's already been breached, the banner doesn't change anything.

bug
I'm currently sitting at 2456 reputation, which is enough and not enough reputation for my next privilege at the same time.

