Ignored tags dialog picks the wrong tag
Reproduce as follows:

I open the ignore tag dialog and type in "C++". It pops up in the combo box scroll. I click there and now it says that c++ is ignored.




I close the dialog and hit browser refresh. Now it doesn't ignore c++ any longer but ignores the tag c instead. If I had c as a watched tag, it has now been removed. So rather than ignoring tags I'm not interested in, it now ignores tags that I was explicitly interested in...



Same with watched tags - I watched [[tag:c++]], refreshed and now I was watching [[tag:c]].

I think this is the same bug (but with different special characters) as reported here by me.

@PeterJames I wouldn't say it's the same bug. It's definitely a problem but a different one. I guess unless you consider SE not knowing how tags work, in which case - it's related. But the * has a different issue than + - the new widget assumes you only work with one tag at a time. Once you select a tag, it gets added. The old widget (on the /questions page) instead has an "add" button, so you can type in sometag* and add that as a watch. Which makes sense because tag wildcards exist. Yet, the new widget doesn't allow for that. It works as if you're only adding tags to a question.

I guess the "forgetting how tags work" can also be evidenced by the lack of hide/grey option for ignored tags. Something I asked whether would be possible but got no response for.

The handling of + in the tag name seems to be, to borrow a phrase, double plus ungood.
Searching is equally broken in ignored/watched tags on the front page
Both seem to experience the same issues. I will describe watching but the same applies to ignoring.
No URL encoding while searching
Second, searching for tags with ++ in them doesn't seem to work. You can find c++ itself most likely because it is close to c. But searching for example for c++11 yields the following of which nothing is relevant:



c11
weblogic11g
68hc11
gcc11
rfc1123
erc1155

This is because + has not been URL encoded. When I searched for c++11 the search query made was:
https://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=c++11&limit=6&timestamp=1730457108515

In URL semantics + is used as a space, so with q=c++11 I have searched for c  11.
If you want an actual + sign, you would encode it as %2B

You can "find" c++ because searching for "c" with two spaces (spaces are ignored) also delivers the C++ tag.

The lack of URL encoding means that # would also be a problem. The same problem we already had: "Go to Wiki" doesn't go to wiki for c# tag
Searching for "c#" in the dialog makes the search query:
https://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=c

Note how it ends immediately after the "c" and misses the   parameters seen in the first request &limit=6&timestamp=1730457108515. That is because the # would be a signifier that the rest of the URL is a fragment and thus excluded from the request to the backend.
Although, I should note that watching c# from the frontend does work. It does not have the same problem as any tag with + in it.
Saving is inconsistent
Even though searching does not necessarily return the correct items, saving is a separate issue. When saving watched tags on the /questions page, I get the following payload sent to the server
fkey=<my fkey>&key=20&value=c%2B%2B+json&forUserId=&render=1

Here I had json watched and added c++. Which produced value=c%2B%2B+json
If I attempt the same on the home page, I instead get
fkey=<my fkey>&key=20&value=json c++

Again lack of URL encoding. Technically that is not needed, since the payload is transferred in the body of the request, therefore, there is no need to encode the payload to make it safe from misinterpretation. However, given that the working widget does URL encode, the backend likely expects encoded data and tries to decode it.
This means that as soon as you save something from the front page, it is already wrong (before reloading)
This also means that saving on the front page will trash all other watches/ignores!
And the behaviour can also be unexpected. Here is one scenario:

You go to the /questions page and add c++ as watched tag.
Go to the front page
Add/remove any other tag from your watched tags list.

This will now change the watch of c++ to c. You would get no feedback for it.
This also happens if a tag exists without the + signs in it. However, consider the following

You go to the /questions page and add visual-c++-6 as watched tag.
Go to the front page
Add/remove any other tag from your watched tags list.

Now you are no longer watching that tag. Nor watching a different tag instead of it, since the + signs will be dropped, however, "visual-c-6" does not exist as a tag. Now you have silently lost a watch altogether

It would seem to be a site-breaking bug even... these changes need a rollback until fixed.

Man, it's too bad we didn't already have a perfectly functional watch/ignore system that got changed for no good reason.

This is the third time within a few months that SE mess up proper URL encoding! What are they even doing?
